# Not creating database using Migration command Update-Database in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created new ASP.Net core project with WebAPI. Using the below link.

[jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login)

I have to use add-migration update-database manually.

Here I add one thing more that I don't know how to debug app in VS Code. After created my project in VS Code I open my project in Visual Studio 2017.

When I about to run the update command `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console. I encounter below error also in my understanding the above command is for create the database and add migrations tables in it. (Correct me If I'm wrong).

```
 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
  Failed executing DbCommand(3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE[AspNetRoles] (

     [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
     [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
      [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
      CONSTRAINT[PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY([Id])
  );
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary2 parameterValues)

 ClientConnectionId:56b94f04-73ff-4391-87fc-36a6c256c650

 Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16

 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary2 parameterValues)

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary2 parameterValues)

 at      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary2 parameterValues)


 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()

 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

 ClientConnectionId:56b94f04-73ff-4391-87fc-36a6c256c650

 Error Number:2714, State:6, Class:16

 There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.`
```

Also I share some of my code here and upload my app on [github](https://github.com/AhmerAli/ASP.Net-Core-2-webapi-Application)

**program.cs**

```
namespace server
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
             WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH"; // todo: get this from somewhere secure
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("server")));

        services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

        // Register the ConfigurationBuilder instance of FacebookAuthSettings
        services.Configure<FacebookAuthSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(FacebookAuthSettings)));

        services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        // jwt wire up
        // Get options from app settings
        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        });

        // api user claim policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
        });

        // add identity
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<EmployeeProfile>(o =>
        {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(
                    async context =>
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                            var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                            if (error != null)
                            {
                                context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                                await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }
                        });
            });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<EmployeeProfile>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<EmployeeProfile> EmployeeProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

My Question is how I create my database using migration update command and what's going wrong in my code.

Comment: nothing going wrong, the exception said you already create the db before create the migration table. you have to delete the db and recreate it

Comment: @aguafrommars but when I see in my ms sql database there was no db created. How can I recreate it?

Comment: did you try to create a context by code ?

Comment: did you try to use the command line `dotnet ef database update` ?

Comment: @agua from mars yes I tried context by code and also use above update command but nothing work in my case. please clone my project and please give your review about my code may be there is something I'm missing.

Comment: When I tried `dotnet ef database update` I recieved :  
Version for package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` could not be resolved.  
So fix that first

Comment: you need to install `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Version 2.0.1` and add this its entry in `.csproj` if not add automatically. Second I solve my problem please see the answer. I appreciate your concern and time.

Comment: vote my comment if that help then

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the answer of my question.

I just need to change my DefaultConnection in both of below files:

`appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`

**Before**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=webapi;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

**After**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=WebApiEfCore;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Then run the below queries.

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial
dotnet ef database update
```

and how its works. Here is an proved snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By removing `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` EntityFrameworkCore will not be able to retrieve multiple sets of data at the same time. You might want to add that back in.