# Entity Framework Core not creating database on update-database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to generate my database using code-first. When I run the command `update-database`, I receive that database cannot be null, but I expected that database would be automatically created. Any idea what I am missing?

```
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public class SmartSchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Professor> Professores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AlunoDisciplina> AlunosDisciplinas { get; set; }

        public SmartSchoolContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SmartSchoolContext>(context => context.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Comment: To start with, I cleaned up your post but it appears you didn't paste part of the code at the beginning there.

Comment: What's the exact command you are running? Are you adding any arguments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not creating database using Migration command Update-Database in ASP.Net Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362092/not-creating-database-using-migration-command-update-database-in-asp-net-core-2)

Comment: i run Add-Migration init, then Update-database

Answer (score 0):

in startup.cs>>ConfigureServices method you have to add

```
services.AddDbContext<SmartSchoolContext>();
```

in configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext context)
{
   // migrate database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
        context.Database.Migrate();
   // other logic

}
```

note:: add and update database using command make sure your database connection is open

Comment: I wouldn't recommend automatically migrating the database in production code. The database login the public-facing application is using should generally not have DDL (data definition language) permissions.